# Setting a border on a Shield UI Chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am trying to show a border on my Shield UI Chart. I set it's color:

```
borderColor: 'red',
```

but it won't show. I tried to set the color as hex value:

```
borderColor: '#F01616',
```

but this doesn't help either. However when I set the same value for the charts background:

```
backgroundColor: 'red',
```

it works. What am I dong wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the color correct. You are right that it can be set either as

```
borderColor: 'red',
```

or as

```
borderColor: '#F01616',
```

As I can see from the previous answer and agree to it, the only thing you are missing, is to set the line thickness of your borther. However you need to use borderWidth:

```
borderWidth: 5,
```

using the internal property and not the CSS attribute border-width, at least because there is no CSS embedding.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't set the `border-width`. How does your HTML markup look like?

See [here](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/javascript.chart/api/borderWidth) in the Shield UI Documentation.